# ARM instruction meaning

Tags: assembly, arm

```
 sub     lr,lr,#4
 stmfd   sp!,{lr}
 stmfd   sp!,{r0-r14}^
 mrs     r1,spsr
 stmfd   sp!,{r1}
 bl      irqHandler
 ldmfd   sp!,{r1}
 msr     spsr_cxsf,r1
 ldmfd   sp!,{pc}^
 bl      irqHandler
```

Can anybody help me with this '^' meaning T_T
what is different with

```
stmfd   sp!,{r0-r14}^
```

and

```
stmfd   sp!,{r0-r14}
```

????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [ARM manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/CIHCADDA.html):

> **^**
>
> is an optional suffix. You must not use it in User mode or System
> mode. It has two purposes: If op is LDM and reglist contains the pc
> (r15), in addition to the normal multiple register transfer, the SPSR
> is copied into the CPSR. This is for returning from exception
> handlers. Use this only from exception modes. Otherwise, data is
> transferred into or out of the User mode registers instead of the
> current mode registers.